# New branch from origin or unmerged branch when working on new JIRA?

Tags: git, merge

Want to know the practice. Say there is an upstream and I forked from there.

For each JIRA ticket I am going to work on, I will create a new local branch from my origin. Things are smooth when I finish the JIRA, I push the branch to my origin, create a pull request to the upstream, and after it is merged, I pull from the upstream and start from there.

I am not sure, if the JIRA branch, after pushed, hasn't been merged to the upstream yet and I am ready to work on a new JIRA. Then do you create a new local branch for the new JIRA based on

- the previous unmerged JIRA local branch (i.e. with the unmerged changes)

or

- the parent of the previous unmerged JIRA (i.e. without the changes you did in the unmerged JIRA)

or

- it doesn't matter provided that the files in these two JIRAs have no dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following approach:

- Always create the new feature branch (for your JIRA ticket) based on the upstream branch, ignoring your (and any other people's) unmerged changes. This way, you're always working based on a clean state.
- Before you create your pull request, update your local repo from `upstream` and rebase your feature branch on the incoming changes.

In my opinion/experience, this is the cleanest way of doing things, since you have to rebase your outgoing changes on any incoming changes anyway. It also ensures that each pull request only contains changes from the ticket you're currently working on, and not any other unmerged tickets.

If you start working on your second JIRA ticket based on the first unmerged one, you'll run into the following issues:

- Your second PR will not only contain the fixes from the second ticket, but also the changes from the first unmerged PR, which might not have an impact in the long run, but will pollute the second PR with unrelated changes.
- Since you're probably not the only person working on the code, you have to do the `pull/rebase` step anyway before creating your PR, since other people's changes might have been merged into the upstream repo in the meantime.

You might want to take a look at [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), which suggests a similar branching model, with one dedicated, independent feature branch per feature.

Another popular branching model that uses Pull Request is the [GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) model.

Comment: Thanks for this clean idea. Could you please comment on the effects of branching off from unmerged changes as oppose to this?

Comment: Thanks, thats quite nice. Picked as answer. Although I still have a one more question: what if I dont' wait for merge but simply create merge requests for the JIRAs I finished (all branched from the clean state as you suggested), what would happen when the code reviewer do all these merges?

Comment: Someone will have to update the "stale" pull requests with the current state, e.g. through a rebase. That can be either you (which is the common way in the [GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) branching model), or it can be the person that does the merge.